# How to fit a poisson distribution with seaborn?

Tags: scipy, seaborn, poisson

I try to fit my data to a poisson distribution:

```
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats as stats

sns.distplot(x, kde = False, fit = stats.poisson)
```

But I get this error:

AttributeError: 'poisson_gen' object has no attribute 'fit'

Other distribution (gamma, etc) de work well.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2184

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) (implemented in scipy as [`scipy.stats.poisson`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html)) is a [*discrete* distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteDistribution.html).  The discrete distributions in scipy do not have a `fit` method.

I'm not very familiar with the [`seaborn.distplot`](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) function, but it appears to assume that the data comes from a continuous distribution.  If that is the case, then even if `scipy.stats.poisson` had a `fit` method, it would not be an appropriate distribution to pass to `distplot`.

---

The question title is "How to fit a poisson distribution with seaborn?", so for the sake of completeness, here's one way to get a plot of the data and its fit.  `seaborn` is only used for the bar plot, using @mwaskom's suggestion to use `seaborn.countplot`.  The fitting is actually trivial, because the maximum likelihood estimation for the Poisson distribution is simply the mean of the data.

First, the imports:

```
In [136]: import numpy as np

In [137]: from scipy.stats import poisson

In [138]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [139]: import seaborn
```

Generate some data to work with:

```
In [140]: x = poisson.rvs(0.4, size=100)
```

These are the values in the `x`:

```
In [141]: k = np.arange(x.max()+1)

In [142]: k
Out[142]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Use `seaborn.countplot` to plot the data:

```
In [143]: seaborn.countplot(x, order=k, color='g', alpha=0.5)
Out[143]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x114700490>
```

The maximum likelihood estimation of the Poisson parameter is simply the mean of the data:

```
In [144]: mlest = x.mean()
```

Use `poisson.pmf()` to get the expected probability, and multiply by the size of the data set to get the expected counts, and then plot using `matplotlib`.  The bars are the counts of the actual data, and the dots are the expected counts of the fitted distribution:

```
In [145]: plt.plot(k, poisson.pmf(k, mlest)*len(x), 'go', markersize=9)
Out[145]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x114da74d0>]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: "It can also (...) plot the estimated PDF over the data." Yes, it seems like the assumption. PDF (probability density function) implies a continuous random variable.

Comment: I would say it's possible to show a discrete distribution with `distplot`, but might involve tweaking several parameters. `countplot` could be a better choice (make sure you use `order=`).

Comment: @mwaskom Thanks for the tip.  I added a plot generated with `countplot` to the answer.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser very nice!

Comment: This really helped me out, @WarrenWeckesser. Thanks a lot.