# Is there a .fit function for discrete distributions in scipy stats?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, mle

I am trying to .fit a Poisson distribution to calculate a MLE for my data. I noticed there is a .fit for continuous functions in scipy stats, but no .fit for discrete functions. Is there another API that has a .fit function for discrete distributions in Python?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500406/how-to-fit-a-poisson-distribution-with-seaborn

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another API that has a .fit function for discrete distributions in Python?

As of SciPy 1.9.0, yes: [scipy.stats.fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fit.html).