# Fitting For Discrete Data: Negative Binomial, Poisson, Geometric Distribution

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution

In scipy there is no support for fitting discrete distributions using data. I know there are a lot of subject about this.

For example if i have an array like below:

> x = [2,3,4,5,6,7,0,1,1,0,1,8,10,9,1,1,1,0,0]

I couldn't apply for this array:

```
from scipy.stats import nbinom
param = nbinom.fit(x)
```

But i would like to ask you up to date, is there any way to fit for these three discrete distributions and then choose the best fit for the discrete dataset?

Comment: What do you mean, there is no support? What about https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html?

Comment: i edited my question @mkrieger1

Comment: What is `x` supposed to mean? What did you expect `nbinom.fit(x)` to do? `scipy.stats.nbinom` has no `fit` method.

Comment: i know that "no fit method". i want to learn is there any way to fit these discrete distributions and getting its parameters or not... @mkrieger1

Comment: FYI: For Poisson, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500406/how-to-fit-a-poisson-distribution-with-seaborn/37500643#37500643

Comment: thank you, burlt i am trying to find fitting for all discrete distributions and piking the best fitting @Weckesser.

Comment: There is no generic method to fit arbitrary discrete distribution, as there is an infinite number of them, with potentially unlimited parameters. There are methods to fit a particular distribution, though, e.g. Method of Moments. If you only need these three I can show how to use it

Comment: @Marat, i d like that. it can be super-helpful for me, thank you.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I know it's not your responsibility or anything, but the decision to omit 'fit' methods from all discrete distributions seems like a pretty weak design choice. Surely it's reasonable to provide methods for the commonly-used discrete distributions. Oh well, I won't worry about it.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Method of Moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics)) to fit any particular distribution.

Basic idea: get empirical first, second, etc. moments, then derive distribution parameters from these moments.

So, in all these cases we only need two moments. Let's get them:

```
import pandas as pd
# for other distributions, you'll need to implement PMF
from scipy.stats import nbinom, poisson, geom

x = pd.Series(x)
mean = x.mean()
var = x.var()
likelihoods = {}  # we'll use it later
```

Note: I used pandas instead of numpy. That is because numpy's `var()` and `std()` don't apply [Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_correction), while pandas' do. If you have 100+ samples, there shouldn't be much difference, but on smaller samples it could be important.

Now, let's get parameters for these distributions. [Negative binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial) has two parameters: p, r.  Let's estimate them and calculate likelihood of the dataset:

```
# From the wikipedia page, we have:
# mean = pr / (1-p)
# var = pr / (1-p)**2
# without wiki, you could use MGF to get moments; too long to explain here
# Solving for p and r, we get:

p = 1 - mean / var  # TODO: check for zero variance and limit p by [0, 1]
r = (1-p) * mean / p
```

**UPD:** Wikipedia and scipy are using different definitions of p, one treating it as probability of success and another as probability of failure. So, to be consistent with scipy notion, use:

```
p = mean / var
r = p * mean / (1-p)
```

**END OF UPD**

**UPD2:**

I'd suggest using @thilak's code log likelihood instead. It allows to avoid loss of precision, which is especially important on large samples.

**END OF UPD2**

Calculate likelihood:

```
likelihoods['nbinom'] = x.map(lambda val: nbinom.pmf(val, r, p)).prod()
```

Same for [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), there is only one parameter:

```
# from Wikipedia,
# mean = variance = lambda. Nothing to solve here
lambda_ = mean
likelihoods['poisson'] = x.map(lambda val: poisson.pmf(val, lambda_)).prod()
```

Same for [Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution):

```
# mean = 1 / p  # this form fits the scipy definition
p = 1 / mean

likelihoods['geometric'] = x.map(lambda val: geom.pmf(val, p)).prod()
```

Finally, let's get the best fit:

```
best_fit = max(likelihoods, key=lambda x: likelihoods[x])
print("Best fit:", best_fit)
print("Likelihood:", likelihoods[best_fit])
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: thank you so much. I have one more question, I'd appreciate it if you could answer it. I know that my dataset is discrete but let's say I wanted to see if it fits the normal distribution or not. Is it possible? Is there any way to do this like Method of Moments?

Comment: and also, can we apply this method to mixture models? like binomial mixture?

Comment: @Salih yes, it works for continuous distributions like Gaussian. In some cases, however, it is hard or even impossible to estimate all parameters. For example, for a mixture of two binomials you'll need three parameters and thus three moment; it is already unpleasant to solve. It gets even worse once you add more components into the mixture.

Comment: @Maral, how do I do it if I want to do it for binomial mixture for two? Could you please show me the way?

Comment: @Salih Sorry, but I will not. It already deviates from the scope of the original question, so maybe it's better to post a separate question for that. Also, it is actually five parameters, not three, and as I mentioned it gets really unpleasant to solve it in a closed form. In practice, mixture models are usually estimated using EM algorithm and gaussians.

Comment: @Maral, are you sure for negative binomial above code? When I generate random data, it does not give the correct result for that distribution.

Comment: @Salih, the posted code actually doesn't work for the questions data, as p>1, right? What is the previous step to take before implementing your algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Marat's great answer, I would most certainly recommend taking log of the probability mass function. Some information on why log likelihood is preferred over likelihood- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892832/why-we-consider-log-likelihood-instead-of-likelihood-in-gaussian-distribution

I would rewrite the code for Negative Binomial to-

```
log_likelihoods = {}
log_likelihoods['nbinom'] = x.map(lambda val: nbinom.logpmf(val, r, p)).sum()
```

Note that I have used-

- logpmf instead of pmf
- sum instead of product

And to find out the best distribution-

```
best_fit = max(log_likelihoods, key=lambda x: log_likelihoods[x])
print("Best fit:", best_fit)
print("log_Likelihood:", log_likelihoods[best_fit])
```